# Openshift + flask wont allow more than one page to be enabled

Tags: python-3.x, flask, openshift, jinja2

When I have only one web page enabled the website works(except for some reason it's got the default orange theme of html5 boilerplate, when I changed that, and when I run it locally it works fine, with gray theme) with the following code in the "flaskapp.py" file.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, \
render_template, abort, send_from_directory, session, escape

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('flaskapp.cfg')#This is the config file that is used by the server to see what it needs

@app.route('/')#The defualt page
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') #Load the index html page


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But when I change it to the following:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, \
render_template, abort, send_from_directory, session, escape

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('flaskapp.cfg')#This is the config file that is used by the server to see what it needs

@app.route('/')#The defualt page
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') #Load the index html page

@app.route('/download-games')#The dpwnloads page
def download-games():
    return "Download"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I get 503 service temporarily unavailable error. HTML file is at http://pastebin.com/32Ctsnjn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyphens are not allowed in Python method names.

Change it to

```
def download_games():
    return "Download"
```